# Recursive function not returning Label in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to return the Label match however I seem to be doing something wrong here.  Can someone push me in the right direction?

```
console.log('start');

var test = {
    "ID": 234324,
    "Label": "KDF",
    "children": [{
        "ID": 234234,
        "Label": "KJDF",
        "children": [{
            "ID": 234324,
            "Label": "KJDF"
        }, {
            "ID": 22323,
            "Label": "LKNDF"
        }, {
            "ID": 34535,
            "Label": "LKNSF"
        }]
    }, {
        "ID": 323434,
        "Label": "CLK"
    }]
}

function testThis(thing, ID) {
    if (thing.ID == ID) {
        console.log('match!')
        return thing.Label;
    } else if (thing.children && thing.children.length) {
        thing.children.forEach(function(x) {
            console.log(x);
            return testThis(x, ID);
        })
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }



}




console.log(testThis(test, 323434));

console.log('end');
```

Comment: Why did you delete your code?

Comment: As it is now, the question makes no sense.

Comment: I rolled back your question because the code you had is still visible in the revisions and your edit now makes your question rather useless.  If you edit again, please explain why you're removing the bulk (and useful portions) of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting `forEach` to return something and leave the loop.  It always returns `undefined` and always iterates **every** element.

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
>   end of a chain.

See [MDN forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

The [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) might serve you better since it will only execute **some** of the elements and returns a value.

---

See working code below:

```js
console.log('start');

var test = {
  "ID": 1,
  "Label": "A",
  "children": [{
    "ID": 2,
    "Label": "B",
    "children": [{
      "ID": 5,
      "Label": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": 6,
      "Label": "F"
    }, {
      "ID": 7,
      "Label": "G"
    }]
  }, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Label": "C"
  }, {
    "ID": 4,
    "Label": "D",
    "children": [{
      "ID": 8,
      "Label": "H"
    }, {
      "ID": 9,
      "Label": "I"
    }]
  }]
}

function testThis(thing, ID) {
  if (thing.ID == ID) {
    console.log('match!')
    return thing.Label;
  } else if (thing.children && thing.children.length) {
    var theone = null;
    thing.children.some(function(x) {
      theone = testThis(x, ID);
      return theone;
    })
    return theone;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

alert(testThis(test, 5));

console.log('end');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you do

```
thing.children.forEach(function(x) {
```

use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.forEach()`, like this

```
return thing.children.some(function(x) {})
```

`.forEach()` returns undefined, while `.some()` will return either `true` or `false` and will stop iterating once `true`is returned.

> `some()` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, some() immediately returns `true`. Otherwise, `some()` returns `false`.

Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/7ebr6pna/**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use foreach for that, use a normal `for` like this

```
function testThis(thing, ID) {
    if (thing.ID == ID) {
        return thing.Label;
    } else if (thing.children && thing.children.length) {
        var label;
        var length = thing.children.length
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            label = testThis(thing.children[i], ID);
            if(label) {
                return label;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could just do `return label` without the check there.

Comment: @MitchKarajohn `if(label)` is needed because if it's `false` and I return it I'm not checking the next item but only the first one